# ExecutorService. Как обратиться к переменной из потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть следующий минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        int done = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.submit((Runnable) () -> {
                System.out.println("Doing something...");
                done++;
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println(done);
    }
    
}
```

Как посчитать не количество итераций, а именно количество завершенных потоков (submit-ов)? Пытаюсь сделать это с помощью переменной `done`, но получаю следующее исключение:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> Local variable done defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Можете использовать вместо int AtomicInteger. Можно вынести done на уровень переменной класса. И почитайте про замыкания.

Comment: А с какой целью считаешь? Если для того, чтобы где-то что-то запустить, то `CountDownLatch` будет лучшим решением, чем `AtomicInteger`

Comment: Хочу сделать `ProgressBar`, используя `JavaFX`...это если кратко...

Comment: Тогда возможно стоит рассмотреть родные для JavaFX вещи: property binding и подобное.  В этом подходе будет примерно так: `SimpleDoubleProperty` счётчик прогресса. Каждый поток обновляет его используя `Platform.runLater`. Сам прогресс бар подписывается на изменение проперти и обновляет себя. Тут примеры https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm  (правда Platform.runLater не упоминается, а зря)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как подсказано в комментариях, для соблюдения указанного требования следует использовать `AtomicInteger` в качестве контейнера значения и его методы `getAndIncrement() / get()`, либо использовать статическую переменную (на уровне класса), или же объявить локальную переменную как массив:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class MyClass {
    
    static int done = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        int[] arr = {0};
        AtomicInteger at = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.submit((Runnable) () -> {
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " done, values changed: atomic=" + at.getAndIncrement() + "; static=" + done++ + "; arr=" + arr[0]++);
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Main thread '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "': atomic: " + at.get() + "; static: " + done + "; arr: " + arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Результаты:

```
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=0; static=0; arr=0
Main thread 'main': atomic: 0; static: 0; arr: 0
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=1; static=1; arr=1
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=2; static=2; arr=2
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=3; static=3; arr=3
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=4; static=4; arr=4
```

При такой реализации главный поток завершает выполнение раньше, чем успеют завершиться потоки, запущенные при помощи `ExecutorService`.

---

Если нужно, чтобы главный поток `main` дождался окончания остальных потоков, следует использовать [`ExecutorService::awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

```java
public class MyClass {
    static int done = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        int[] arr = {0};
        AtomicInteger at = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.submit((Runnable) () -> {
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " done, values changed: atomic=" + at.getAndIncrement() + "; static=" + done++ + "; arr=" + arr[0]++);
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("Main thread '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "': atomic: " + at.get() + "; static: " + done + "; arr: " + arr[0]);
    }
}
```

```
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=0; static=0; arr=0
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=1; static=1; arr=1
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=2; static=2; arr=2
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=3; static=3; arr=3
Thread pool-1-thread-1 done, values changed: atomic=4; static=4; arr=4
Main thread 'main': atomic: 5; static: 5; arr: 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы предложил ещё вариант - поместить все Future в список и в нужном месте посчитать, сколько из них завершилось.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        List<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Future<?> future = executorService.submit((Runnable) () -> {
                System.out.println("Doing something...");
            });
            futures.add(future);
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        long done = futures.stream().filter(Future::isDone).count();
        System.out.println(done);
    }
```